# How to create a Issue with custom "Reporter" from a JIRA Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jira, jira-rest-api

Acccording to https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby rails gem I have to setup a valid jira user and api password to allow me access Jira api.

I can create issue according to the follow code but when I see the record logs or even in the Jira page the Reporter title goes with my username. I need to create the Issue username "reporter" from my html input form which I don't know what my user will type...

So how can I create an Issue with custom usernames user Rails Jira gem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their test suite:

```
JIRA::Resource::Issue.new(client, attrs: {
                                  'id' => '123',
                                  'fields' => {
                                    'reporter' => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'assignee'    => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'project'     => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'priority'    => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'issuetype'   => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'status'      => { 'foo' => 'bar' },
                                    'components'  => [{ 'foo' => 'bar' }, { 'baz' => 'flum' }],
                                    'versions'    => [{ 'foo' => 'bar' }, { 'baz' => 'flum' }],
                                    'comment'     => { 'comments' => [{ 'foo' => 'bar' }, { 'baz' => 'flum' }] },
                                    'attachment'  => [{ 'foo' => 'bar' }, { 'baz' => 'flum' }],
                                    'worklog'     => { 'worklogs' => [{ 'foo' => 'bar' }, { 'baz' => 'flum' }] }
                                  }
                                })
    end
```

Which means you should be able to write:

```
issue = client.Issue.build
issue.save({"fields"=>{"reporter"=> {"username" => "reporter"},"summary" => {"Crazy froggy"}}
```

I'm guessing as to "username" being the appropriate key here - but if they're calling this in a spec, then you should be able to call it in your code.

Now the *problem* may be that "reporter" isn't a valid user within Jira - because their spec tests:

```
    it 'has the correct relationships' do
      expect(subject).to have_one(:reporter, JIRA::Resource::User)
      expect(subject.reporter.foo).to eq('bar')
```

The `expect(subject).to have_one(:reporter, JIRA::Resource::User)` line suggests that the 'reporter' value has to be a valid instance of JIRA::Resource::User which tells me that you cannot set this field to whatever you want.  I think that JIRA charges based on how many accounts you have for your JIRA instance?  So each User would be a separate license.

I'm doing a lot of guesswork here - but I think this means you need to pay to license the 'reporter' User within JIRA, and then you could set it for all these issues.

Comment: Great for your answer, finally I figured out. Actually  we can have user as customers for free but the Jira api is not so clear about that... I had to figure out by myself. I had to reach two routes. `https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/customer` do create a user customer, get the accountId and then reach `https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue` to be possible to create the Jira issue with custom Reporter Any way thank s a lot for your time.

Comment: Great - glad that you figured it out :)